# Irreducible polynomial of an element in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

In Rotman's Galois Theory, he defines separability for elements in field extensions as such:

> Definition: If E/F is an extension, then $\alpha\in E$ is called separable if either
> it is transcendental or its irreducible polynomial is separable.

I have never heard of the irreducible polynomial for an element of a field? My assumption is that $\alpha$ is algebraic of degree $n$, then the irreducible polynomial that Rotman is referring to is the unique monic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ $f(x) \in F[x]$ satisfying $f(\alpha) = 0$.

However, I'm unsure and couldn't find anything on Google. Could someone verify this for me?

Comment: I don't think anyone would say that non-algebraic elements are separable. And the standard terminology is (the $F$-) minimal polynomial, not irreducible polynomial.

Comment: @reuns I see. However, my course uses Rotman and a homework problem deals with separability in a tower of field extensions, so I assume that we're restricted to Rotman's definition for the exercise, especially considering we didn't really review the concept in class.